# How can i create generic dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello i have this IntArray i want to convert to accept generic types:

```
class IntArray {

private:
    int* first_cell = nullptr;
    int size = 0; // currently occupied elements
    int capacity = 8; // size of the allocated memory

public:
    IntArray() {
        first_cell = new int[capacity]; // Declare the array in memory
    }

    IntArray(const IntArray& src)
        : size(src.size),
        capacity(src.capacity)
    {
        first_cell = new int[capacity];
        std::copy_n(src.first_cell, size, first_cell);
    }

    IntArray(IntArray&& src)
        : first_cell(src.first_cell),
        size(src.size),
        capacity(src.capacity)
    {
        src.first_cell = nullptr;
        src.size = src.capacity = 0;
    }

    ~IntArray() {
        delete[] first_cell;
    }

    IntArray& operator=(IntArray rhs) {
        IntArray temp(std::move(rhs));
        std::swap(first_cell, temp.first_cell);
        std::swap(size, temp.size);
        std::swap(capacity, temp.capacity);
        return *this;
    }

    void push_back(int number) {
        if (size == capacity) {
            int new_cap = capacity * 2; // increased capacity
            int* new_arr = new int[new_cap]; // new arr with new capacity

            for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) {
                new_arr[k] = first_cell[k]; // copy data from frist array
            }

            delete[] first_cell; // remove first array

            first_cell = new_arr;
            capacity = new_cap;
        }
        first_cell[size] = number;
        ++size;
    }

    int length() {
        return size;
    }

    int index_of(int number) {
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            
            if (number == first_cell[k]) {
                
                return k;
            }           
        }
        return -1;
    }



    void print(char symb) {
        for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) {            
            std::cout << first_cell[k] << symb;
        }
    }
};
```

How can i convert this array it to accept any type like generic array? I want to be able to accept any types is this possible? And how do i check the types? If you can point me in the right direction because i have no idea how it can be done? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a single array to have multiple types, or do you want to be able to create a homogeneous array of any type?

Comment: This smells like homework. Do some work first, and come back when you encounter an error you can't overcome. Read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: @sweenish Not homework bro i just want to know how to do it for personal project.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Bassicaly i want to to have array that can be of any type and i get to choose the type when i initialize the array or like you said array of any type whichever will work better.

Comment: You should look into templates.

Comment: Notice that [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out;

```
template<class T>
class List {

private:
    T* first_cell = nullptr;
    int size = 0; // currently occupied elements
    int capacity = 8; // size of the allocated memory

public:
    List() {
        first_cell = new T[capacity]; // Declare the array in memory
    }

    List(const List& src)
        : size(src.size),
        capacity(src.capacity)
    {
        first_cell = new T[capacity];
        std::copy_n(src.first_cell, size, first_cell);
    }

    List(List&& src)
        : first_cell(src.first_cell),
        size(src.size),
        capacity(src.capacity)
    {
        src.first_cell = nullptr;
        src.size = src.capacity = 0;
    }

    ~List() {
        delete[] first_cell;
    }

    List& operator=(List rhs) {
        List temp(std::move(rhs));
        std::swap(first_cell, temp.first_cell);
        std::swap(size, temp.size);
        std::swap(capacity, temp.capacity);
        return *this;
    }

    void push_back(int number) {
        if (size == capacity) {
            int new_cap = capacity * 2; // increased capacity
            T* new_arr = new T[new_cap]; // new arr with new capacity

            for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) {
                new_arr[k] = first_cell[k]; // copy data from frist array
            }

            delete[] first_cell; // remove first array

            first_cell = new_arr;
            capacity = new_cap;
        }
        first_cell[size] = number;
        ++size;
    }

    int length() {
        return size;
    }

    int first_index_of(int number) {
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            
            if (number == first_cell[k]) {
                
                return k;
            }           
        }
        return -1;
    }



    void print(char symb) {
        for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) {            
            std::cout << first_cell[k] << symb;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice work, It's important you understand that this is actually a template definition. This will reduce code duplication, but each time you instantiate a template you actually define a new class.